# Canvas not showing/drawing anything in Windows Chrome

Tags: windows, canvas

I have a problem that the code below works in : *IE 10*, *Firefox*, *Safari*, *Mac Chrome*, but not for *Windows Chrome*.

```
$(function () {
    var video_dom = document.querySelector('#v');
    var canvas_draw = document.querySelector('#c');

    var draw_interval = null;

    video_dom.addEventListener('play', function () {
        video_dom.width = canvas_draw.width = video_dom.offsetWidth;
        video_dom.height = canvas_draw.height = video_dom.offsetHeight;
        var ctx_draw = canvas_draw.getContext('2d');
        draw_interval = setInterval(function () {
            ctx_draw.drawImage(video_dom, 0, 0, video_dom.width, video_dom.height);
            var dataURL = canvas_draw.toDataURL();
            document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
        }, 3500)

    }, false);
})();
```

Also I get this error in console like: `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`.
 
Why is the canvas is working in the *Mac* version, but not the *Windows* version of *Chrome*?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you're using a dollar sign ($) in front of your function when you're not using jQuery.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var video_dom = document.querySelector('#v');
    var canvas_draw = document.querySelector('#c');

    ...

};
```

Should be clear of errors.

Comment: I did that and still canvas not working on modern chrome browsers :(